# how to put half of collection view cell above the UIView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview

I want to put half of the CollectionView cell above the `UIView`. Is it possible in iOS swift? how?

i tried put programitically `UIView` in `CollectionView` but it didn't work. i set top section insets . but it did not work.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/devxoul/UICollectionViewFlexLayout

Comment: Please show what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @AshleyMills, **Please show what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc** is right. but i continuously read the same comment about how to ask and other things in many of your question.

Comment: @Pankil I'm not sure what you're saying. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your collection view on top of another view and set the background colour of the collection view to `clear`.

[image]

Regarding your question from the comment about the constraints:

[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you. but then how  to set constrain of both? collectionview top constrain set to the safe area of the view controller right? and view bottom constrain set to the view controller's bottom side  right?

Comment: In a storyboard you can do the following:
1. hover your mouse above the collection view (not a cell).
2. hold control key 
3. tap and hold
4. drag your mouse on the blue view
5. release tap and key
6. select vertical spacing

(I've added images to explain)

Comment: one problem is when i scroll collection view at that time that collection view 's blue part is remain same. that part is also scroll with the collection view. but it did not move up side. what to do?

Comment: You could implement scroll delegate and update the constraint.constant value based on the content offset based on the solution above (which is not the only way to handle this situation).

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the base view first and then add the collection view on top of it adjust the frames or autolayout constraints according to your need and then you can set the background color of your collectionview as clear color.

To achieve the above effect you will need to set the background color of your collection view cell as clear too and add insets accordingly.